# Does jquery have an equivalent of dojo.subscribe()?

Tags: jquery, dojo

Forgive my ignorance as I am not as familiar with jquery. Is there an equivalent to dojo.subscribe() ?

Do you know a solution in jquery ? There are jquery.connect but this plugin not work in my tests.

Comment: Found something about it: http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/subscribe

Comment: I am working on a plugin work with Spring-js and JQuery. Spring-js uses Dojo to resolve all Ajax communication, so I am trying to convert the Spring-Dojo.js to Spring-Jquery.js, here is the JS file: http://www.koders.com/javascript/fid2238090329B931C75C62EA4108142E5019C4D837.aspx?s=window#L261. At the moment I do not know how to convert dojo.subscribe(this.elementId+"/validation", this, "_handleValidation"); on the 143 line.

Answer (score 1):

Best guess from the description of subscribe in [j08691's link](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/subscribe): [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) and [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/). These allow you to define arbitrarily-named events on DOM nodes and later call them with arguments.

It sounds like the dojo.subscribe does this document-globally; you could probably achieve the same by binding events to the document object itself but I suspect whatever you're doing it'll make sense to bind events to DOM nodes on your page instead.

e.g. your example script contains

```
this.validationSubscription
    = dojo.subscribe(this.elementId+"/validation", this, "_handleValidation");
```

You could instead

```
var _this = this;
$(element).bind("validation",
    function(event, flag) { _this._handleValidation(flag)); }
    );
```

and then later

```
$(element).trigger("validation", false);
```

Comment: Thanks! But sorry again, How could I convert the next line? this.connection = dojo.connect(element, this.event, this, "submit");

Comment: OK, I don't really know what dojo connect does either but [guessing from this](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/connect.html) it's about binding functions to events on DOM nodes? In that case use bind again, or one of the specific bind helpers such as [submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) - just pass them the name of the event and the function you want to execute. jQuery will trigger all bound events in sequence unless one of them signals the event to stop propagation, or `return false;` which stops propagation (and disables default event behaviour) too